# Is there a way for a PC to craft crossbow bolts?

Tags: dnd-5e, crafting, ammunition

In *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 85, it lists the following as one of the things you can do with [Woodcarver's Tools](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#WoodcarversTools):

> ***Craft Arrows.*** As part of a short rest, you can craft up to five arrows. As part of a long rest, you can craft up to twenty. You must have enough wood on hand to produce them.

Are the any rules that allow a PC to craft crossbow bolts, similar to the above?

Comment: What makes you think that the examples they give in XGtE are *exclusively* the only things you can do with those tools?

Comment: @illustro Nothing, but that's not my question. Before asking my DM about this, it would be good if something already exists (as it does for arrows); if not, I'll present this and ask the DM's opinion (I mean, it's the DM's decision either way, but it'll be more convincing with an actual RAW option).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not pose an “actual problem”

Comment: @AmethystWizard This looks like a legitimate question to me. Crafting crossbow bolts isn't some weird edge case but potentially a rather common activity (it should be as common as crafting arrows).

Comment: @AmethystWizard I have no idea how you could possibly conclude that. I assure you, I really want to know how to do this in-game, and was just looking for a RAW method.

Comment: @AmethystWizard Please reread the Meta on your question. Your question was not closed only because it lacked an actual problem as several of the answers there pointed out. It was closed because you ran into our community's ["quality alarm"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9767/28591). Voting to close other questions is not an appropriate or effective way to get it reopened, nor is this an appropriate use of comments under someone else's question. If you think the question should be reopened, we have appropriate methods for bringing it to the community's attention.

Comment: Understood, “The take away here is to ask about problems you are actually having.” Applies to me and not others because when I ask such questions they are “odd”, “contrived”, “suspicious”, but when others do ask questions without a clear “actual problem” they don’t run into the “quality alarm”.

Comment: @AmethystWizard So, it is clear from what you are saying that we aren't  communicating properly since that is not at all what the takeaway is. Would you be interested in us opening a private chat with the moderation team to hear what you have to say and to try to work through whatever barriers we are tripping over here? (sometime when it is convenient for you and for at least one of us, naturally)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Simple crafting during downtime?

The rules for crafting during downtime on page 187 of the PHB state:

> You can craft nonmagical objects, including adventuring equipment and works of art. You must be proficient with tools related to the object you are trying to create (typically artisan's tools). You might also need access to special materials or locations necessary to create it. For example, someone proficient with smith's tools needs a forge in order to craft a sword or suit of armor.
> For every day of downtime you spend crafting, you can craft one or more items with a total market value not exceeding 5 gp, and you must expend raw materials worth half the total market value...

Surely if you can craft weapons and armour you could craft ammunition as well.

## Otherwise simply apply the same rules for crafting arrows that you've quoted from Xanathar's Guide to Everything (XGtE).

[Modern Crossbow bolts (much like modern arrows) are typically made from carbon or aluminium](http://www.bestcrossbowsource.com/crossbow-bolts-arrows-guide/) but [they can also be made from hard wood](https://medievalcrossbow.info/crossbow-bolts/) with some form of steel tip (again, much like arrows) so there's no reason the sames rules for arrows couldn't be applied to bolts (or a slightly modified version).

One thing to remember though is that D&D is not a simulation for real life. The specific materials, techniques or construction methods of the real world may not translate that well into TTRPG rules so don't get too bogged down thinking about it. **There's no reason to reinvent the wheel; might as well just use the rules that are already provided.**

XGtE even states on page 77 that:

> The material in this chapter is meant to make your life easier. Ignore anything you find here that doesn't help you, and don't hesitate to customize the things that you do use. The game's rules exist to serve you and the games you run. As always, make them your own.